# Find the volume of a rectangular parallelpiped

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me with this problem? I used the following drawing in solving this problem and got a wrong answer. I don't know whether it is due to my misunderstanding of the problem. Here is my understanding of the problem. 
1). The sum of all red line = 28, 
2). Green line $AD=2\sqrt{10}$, 
3). Green line $CH=3\sqrt{5}$.

> A rectangular parallelpiped has rectangles for all its faces. The sum of the lengths of the four diagonals of a rectangular parllelpiped is 28. The diagonal of one face has length $2\sqrt{10}$, while the diagonal of another face has length $3\sqrt{5}$. Find he number of cubic units in the volume of the rectangular parallelpiped.

[image]

Comment: The diagonals of the parallelepiped are $AH,ED,GB$, and $CF$. Your red lines are all diagonals of faces, not of the solid.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank  you! Does the problem assume ABCD is square? If not, are the green lines in the figure right?

Comment: No, there’s no assumption about the relative lengths of any of the sides. To match up your picture with my answer, I’m taking $y$ to be the length of $CD$, the side that the $ABCD$ and $CDHG$ faces have in common, $x$ to be the length of $AC$, and $z$ to be the length of $CG$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve incorrectly identified the diagonals of the solid: they are actually $AH,ED,GB$, and $CF$.

Let the dimensions of the solid be $x,y$, and $z$. The length of a diagonal of the solid is then

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\;,$$

so

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{28}4=7\;,\tag{1}$$

and $x^2+y^2+z^2=49$.

There are three different lengths of face diagonals, but any two of them share one side length; we’ll assume that the shared side length is $y$ and let $2\sqrt{10}$ and $3\sqrt5$ be the lengths of the diagonals of the $x\times y$ and $y\times z$ faces, respectively. Thus,

$$x^2+y^2=\left(2\sqrt{20}\right)^2=40\;,\tag{2}$$

and

$$y^2+z^2=\left(3\sqrt5\right)^2=45\;.\tag{3}$$

It follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that

$$x^2+2y^2+z^2=40+45=85$$

and hence from $(1)$ that

$$y^2=85-49=36\;.$$

Everything from here should be pretty straightforward: use $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get $x$ and $z$, respectively, and use $x,y$, and $z$ to get the volume of the solid.